# Laravel error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (0)

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

Hi community Stackoverflow! I need help with this please! :(

```
function e($value, $doubleEncode = true)
    {
        if ($value instanceof Htmlable) {
            return $value->toHtml();
        }
 
        return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);
    }
```

My code is giving me problems right on this line when I click on any link in my app. I've seen similar questions and tried almost everything, but I don't have the solution yet.

Error argument:

```
[]
3
"UTF-8"
true
```

Comment: Somewhere, this function is called with an array as the `$value` argument when it needs to be a string. You should be able to find out where by checking the stack trace.

Comment: I have this here friend @MagnusEriksson function append_config(array $array)
    {
        $start = 9999;

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                $start++;

                $array[$start] = Arr::pull($array, $key);
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }

Comment: I don't see the relevance of that code though.

Comment: `$value` is array and `htmlspecialchars()` need string

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? In version 8, this line looks like this:
`return htmlspecialchars($value ?? '', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);`

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere in the blade template. Try to check the stack trace from which the blade is. Because every text / string you have in the blade is automatically escaped using this e() function. And somewhere you're probably trying to accidentally print an array instead of a string.

Comment: I can't see the error, my Laravel version is 7 =(

Comment: I'm new with Laravel, the problem is with a platform that a I buy!

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/u253484860/domains/reduxpty.tk/public_html/resources/views/admin/managements/updater.blade.php)

Comment: It may be a more complex problem. Start by finding out which displayed text is the problem in the given file (updater.blade.php). Then find where the value is generated and why it is array instead of string. etc